# Powershell Special characters / Automating build - PSRemoting

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I am using Teamcity and Powershell to automate few builds. Teamcity runs under lets say account A. There are few executable that needs to be run under account B. Account B has access to DB (windows auth integrated security access) and needs to go and create few tables on install. Passwords for account B is saved in the text file. I am having few issues with this.

1) Account B can have any special characters. I am reading XML file (as this file can be saved in a location where only Account A has access) and new up PSCredential to do the PSRemoting. I am using something like

```
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString $passwordFromXMLFile -AsPlainText -Force
$mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("username", $secpasswd)
```

$PasswordFromXMLFile can have any special characters. How should I deal with this?

2) When I try to run the executable in context of account B (after I somehow escaped and connected using this account), I am seeing the executable runs under anonymous account instead of domainname\B account. Is there some setting that I need to make sure it runs under account B.

My code looks something like - this is not the exact code I am just extracting some relevant portion.

```
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString $passwordFromXMLFile -AsPlainText -Force
$mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("B", $secpasswd)
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $serverName -Credential $mycreds
```

I see the session connects fine. to the computer

```
$scriptblock = {
    Start-Process $exeName $arguments - wait
}
invoke-command -session $session -scriptblock  $scriptblock
```

Thoughts? Start-Process runs but it executes on anonymous authority instead of account B.

Comment: Try replacing the Start-Process invocation with just `whoami` and see if you're getting that far running as account B.

Comment: I think we're going to need more detail. First of all I'm not sure what difference special characters would make in the password section. Are you getting an error here? Also, I've tested this and both the session itself and the processes are starting as account B. When you say it's running on anonymous authority, what does that mean? How are you determining that? What process are you starting? Have you tested with something simple like Notepad?

Comment: Tim - if password has special character ($ or other unsupported ps characters) sign - reading it from xml and putting it inside the $secpasswd doesn't work well.
I have been testing this from teamcity as the deployment needs to happen there - I will go back and do the whoami to test this and get back. The console app that's running goes and tries to create some views in SQL with windows auth- and it fails saying NTAuthority\anonymous user. I will get back after putting whoami in there.

Comment: How are you reading your XML? I ran a test and it pulled it in fine with both @ and $. I also tested the whoami step and that seems to work properly as well.

Comment: Tim Ferill / Keith Hill, I finally got with this. Looks like @ and $ is having problems, I used start-process then moved over to system.diagnostics.process. When I run whoamI, I do see that the correct account B is output. But, when I run the process that needs to run under this account using Start-Process orInvoke-Expression or System.Diagnostics.Process - I still get SQL NTAuthority\Anonymous user. When I setup username, domain and password for the diagnostics.processinfo, I am getting- Exception calling "Start" with "0" argument(s): "Access is denied".
This might be because of Elevated user